# Issue with converting text to Latin

Tags: php, mysql, iso-8859-1, utf8-decode, latin

Need to convert below string from UTF-8 to Latin (ISO-8859-1)

```
HÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â¤ger
```

The correct output should be: **Häger**

I have tried this by PHP and MySQL but did not get the desired result.

PHP:

```
<?php
$text = "HÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â¤ger";
$text= utf8_decode($text);
echo $text;
?>
```

> Output : HÃ?Â?Ã?Â?Ã?Â?Ã?Â¤ger

MySQL:

```
select CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT('HÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â¤ger' USING latin1) AS binary) USING utf8)
```

> Output : HÃ?Â?Ã?Â¤ger

Can someone please help here?

Comment: This text is not just converted once to utf8, but more likely multiple times.

Comment: yes, right.. it is multiple times encoded. 
If I use below tool to convert the text in Latin, it is giving proper result. 
[utf8-to-latin-converter](http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/utf8-to-latin-converter.php)
Just I need to covert it multiple times.